# re-assign the value of a column as it changes between rows

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, awk

I need to reassign the value of $2 as it changes between rows.  The only unique variable to control when the value of $2 changes is $2 itself.  So maybe an if statement which considers NR is appropriate.  I am intermediate user of awk, but don't know where to start with this one.

Here is an example input file:

```
1.69 15
1.79 15
1.94 16
2.03 16
2.11 16
2.21 16
2.28 17
2.36 17
```

Desired output:

```
1.69 15
1.79 15
1.94 14
2.03 14
2.11 14
2.21 14
2.28 13
2.36 13
```

So the initial value of $2 remains, then when it changes the values decrease by one relative to the last change.
I'm writing this as a batch script in windows.
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Did you mean `bash` scripting under Linux or `batch` programming under `DOS`?

Comment: batch file under DOS.  I think something like this,  but it does not increment downwards as the value of '(offset-1)' needs to increase:   awk "{if ($2<prev) {offset++}; print ( $1, $2+(offset-1)); prev=$2}" trial_dec.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{m=p=$2} p!=$2{m=m-1;p=$2} {$2=m; print}' file
```

**Explanation:**

Here, `m` - modified , `p` - previous

- `NR==1{m=p=$2}` - Assigning `$2` value in `m` and `p` at first line (`NR == 1`).
- `p!=$2{m=m-1;p=$2}` - If `p` is `!=` to `$2`, then decrement `m` by `1`.
- `{$2=m; print}` - Always assign `m` value to `$2`, then `print` it.

Comment: That works like a charm, can you explain a bit more on how it works? Thank you.

Comment: @J.H, Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Batch file solution that I hope be clear enough; you may review the format of any command executing it with `/?` parameter. The only tricky point is the use of Delayed Expansion, so I suggest you to search for such a term in this site and/or execute `set /?` and carefully read the description and examples about "delayed expansion", that is, variables enclosed in `!exclamation-marks!` instead of `%percent-signs%`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined $2 (
      set "$2=%%b"
      set "prev=%%b"
   ) else if %%b neq !prev! (
      set /A $2-=1
      set "prev=%%b"
   )
   echo %%a !$2!
)
```

If you want to create an output file, enclose *the whole* `for` command in parentheses and redirect the output to the file; that is, start the `for` this way:

```
(for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (input.txt) do (
```

... and end it this way:

```
)) > output.txt
```

After that, you may use a `move /Y output.txt input.txt` command to replace the old file.